# How to curvefit an integral function with probability density in python?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, numerical-integration, probability-density

I'm running python v > 3.0. I have a question regarding curvefitting for an integral function. I have a function with independent variable and two parameters to be estimated. Let's say independent variable is 'X' and parameters are a and b.

X is a gridded data (2 dimensional). At each grid point,'i' X varies between X[i]-4 to X[i]+4 thereby giving rise to a probability density function associated with each grid 'i', which can be X[i]*pdf. X*[i]_pdf is an array with nbins from X[i]-4 to X[i]+4

Function to solve is : E[i] = integral{(X[i]_Pdf) * a* (X[i]**b))

When I solve this, I get c0=nan, p0=inf. My data doesn't contain nan. I would appreciate any help in this regard.

I checked other questions on similar issues but none of them involve a Pdf which makes it tricky.

I'm trying to use curve fit for an integral function that involves a product of the independent variable and its pdf at each point. Pdf is calculated by assuming 2 sigma spread with sigma=2.0 (x[j] - 2*2.0 to x[j] + 2*2.0 in the 'predicted' equation below).

When I solve this, I get c0=nan, p0=inf. My data doesn't contain nan. I would appreciate any help in this regard.

a and b parameters are to be estimated. Here is a snippet of my code.

```py
    import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.stats import norm

X = np.arange(0,30,0.05) # independent variable
y = np.arange(0,3.0,0.005) # dependent variable 


    def integrand(w,a,b):
        return norm.pdf(w) * a* (w**b)

    def fun1_var(X,a,b):
        x = X
        predicted = np.zeros(len(x))
        for j in range(0,len(x)):
            predicted[j] = quad(integrand, x[j]-4,x[j]+4, args=(a, b))[0]
        return predicted

c0,p0 = curve_fit(fun1_var,(X),y)
```

Comment: With what you have provided, I cannot reproduce the problem. Would you please post a minimal working example with all import statements and the minimum amount of data that will reproduce the problem?

Comment: please see code above. I have added a few things.

Comment: This yeilds "NameError: name 'curve_fit' is not defined" as you have not provided code that will run. Again, I cannot reproduce the problem with the code you have provided.

Comment: You should be able to run the code the reproduce the result. Thanks for looking into this. coefficients are nan and variance is inf